# Base64 usage in android studio vs DatatypeConverter

Tags: java, android, base64

I'm fairly new to using Android Studio as opposed to rom os builds, i know there is Base64 which has similar encoding methods as DatatypeConverter but i'm not very familiar with it's usage...A couple of issues i've run into and don't know how to make them work the same as DatatypeConverter:

```
if (fromLogs) {
    payload = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(new String(payload));
}

byte[] rawKey = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encodedKey);
```

can anyone help with the correct syntax for converting this to Base64?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick example of how to convert to and from base 64.

```
//To base64 string.
String encodedKey = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

//From base64 string.
byte[] data = Base64.decode(encodedKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I want to stress that this library is part of the Android API, (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html), not Android Studio.

Comment: apprec the info, i'll give this a shot

Answer (score 1):

following the info in the provided api docs i converted DataTypeConverter to Base64:

```
payload = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(new String(payload)); //not working
payload = Base64.decode(payload, Base64.DEFAULT); //working
```

Comment: Traditionally if someone answers your question you should accept their answer instead of posting your own solution.

Comment: i did, thought it also would be useful to provide the code replacement i used to fix my issue since i haven't seen an actual code example exactly relavant to the usage i was going for

Comment: Thank you for selecting answer. Not to be pedantic, but your solution is essentially identical to the one I posted, (with different variable names and missing a type declaration), that's why I commented the first time. It is unlikely that you will ever get an answer that is *exactly* relevant to your issue, (variable names the same).